# Delete all the data after Re enrolment in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have been using Moodle for the past year. I am facing a problem when I re-enroll a user. This means if I unenroll a user and enroll him again in the course.

The old data like his progress and other things showing in Moodle. But I am working based on the purchase method if he re-enrolls it is like starting a course from scratch.

Please help to find a solution for that.

I'm using Moodle 3.9.11

Comment: I don't think its possible to reset the course for a single user. Maybe try this plugin from Catalyst - https://moodle.org/plugins/local_recompletion